# Can we alter ListBox with css?

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down listbox. Is there a way we can style it with css, such that it "looks more like the button" below it? Obviously that's going to be some design work, I'm just not sure what css properties we have (if any) to play with (screenshot example):

[image: dropdown example]

Where can I find all the css properties for a listbox?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out:

[Style a Select Box Using Only CSS](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)